# Python Nuitka Executable Doesn't Run Without virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, executable, nuitka

The problem: My nuitka executable needs a venv folder, and it needs it to be in the place it was when I compiled the executable.

The steps I took:

1. In the folder where my project is I have an active virtualenv environment under venv. I had installed a couple of python libraries here that my project needs.
2. I build an executable using

```
python -m nuitka src/__main__.py --follow-imports --output-file=run
```

3. When I attempt to run my executable run.exe or the .cmd file, the program works.
4. I rename the venv folder under the project, or try to run this on a different computer, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\feren\PycharmProjects\myproject\src\__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    is_executable = False
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_virtualenv'
```

This is weird for two reasons:

- As you can see from the error, the first line is not an import statement, but a simple bool value being initialised.
- I am not importing that module from anywhere my project

How can I create an executable that either:

- looks for the venv folder with a relative path OR
- the desired solution: have nuitka build all the libraries into the executable

Comment: As far as I know, "nuitka" is not very easy to use, you can try "pyinstaller"

Comment: When I built it using Pyinstaller generated a lot of extra files on the side that appeared to be not my dependencies, and pyinstaller's single file option unpacks everything during runtime so it is very slow.

In an ideal world I don't expose too much about my tech stack to the users of this app. If necessary I currently have an assets folder for my encrypted data files, and if necessary I'll add all the libraries from my sitepackages to another one, but for that I'd need to know how to define a relative path with nuitka.

Comment: Have you tried the "-Fw" parameter of "pyinstaller"? He will not generate other files, even if some additional files are generated in the end, just delete them, and the generated ".exe" files can run anywhere and do not require any dependencies

Comment: I can try but the app is a game and I am really appreciating the better frame rate, and the extra layer of obfuscation compiling to c provides me